# Read a String as a reference to a Variable

Tags: java, string, reference

I want to read a parameter from my class Datasource:

```
public class Datasource {
public final static String M = "M"; 
public final static String M_SHEET ="Config";
public final static String M_LOC = "C6";
public final static int M_DEFAULT = 2; // default value
...
}
```

by using a method changeParameters:

```
public static void changeParameter(String param, double value) {
    String parameter = param.toUpperCase(); // uppercase to match the final variable from Datasource

    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(Datasource.EXCELFILENAME);
    // Excelconnection
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    String sheetName = "Datasource." + parameter + "_SHEET";
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
    String excelCell = "Datasource." + parameter + "_LOC";
    int rowInt = getRow(excelCell);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowInt);
    int cellInt = getCell(excelCell);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellInt);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Datasource. EXCELFILENAME);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

getRow and getCell both take a String as Parameter to get the Excelrow and Excelcolumn. Does anybody know how I can reach that the Strings sheetName and excelCell are not seen as a String but as a reference to the String from Datasource (so that for example the "C6" is accessed and not "Datasource.M_LOC"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for this.

```
Class clazz = DataSource.class;
Field field = clazz.getField("M_LOC"); // use getDeclaredField if the field isn't public
String str = (String)field.get(null); // it's a static field, so no need to pass in a DataSource reference
```

Alternatively, put a hashmap in DataSource with the field name as key and field value as value.

I believe that `getField` and `getDeclaredField` are linear-time methods, so if possible you should cache their results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be referencing things by strings, why are you storing them as individual variables? Why not use a `Map<String, String>`? That way, when you need to access the string referenced by `"Datasource.M_LOC"`, you can use

```
Map<String,String> referenceMap;
...
referenceMap.get(parameter+"_LOC");
```